# Passing values to function with multiple default parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

Consider a function with 3 (arbitrary) parameters, two of which have a default value:

```
const foo = (a, b=1, c=2) => {
    console.log(a,b,c);
}
```

Now, I want parameter **b** to have its default value, and parameter **c** to have the value passed by me. I did something like this:

```
foo(0, c = 10); // Ideally, a = 0, b = 1, c = 10
```

But the output of the function is:

```
0 10 2
```

So, the value of 10 is being passed into parameter **b** instead of **c**. Why is this happening even after I have explicitly passed the value of c? What is the correct way to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: The name of the parameter dosn't matter, only the position matters.

Comment: Try this:  foo(0, undefined , 10);

Comment: So there is no way of doing that (apart from passing parameters as a json)? This works in python. So, I assumed javascript would also have a similar feature.

Comment: as mentioned by @SoluableNonagon, you can pass object, as long as the func. signature allows it, and use destructuring.

Answer (score 7):

You need to pass `undefined` as a parameter for a default to take.

```js
const foo = (a, b=1, c=2) => {
    console.log(a,b,c);
}

console.log(foo(1))

console.log(foo(1, undefined,25))
```

For the kind of signature you're trying to pass consider always passing an object and destructuring

```js
    const foo = ({ a, b=1, c=2 }) => {
        console.log(a,b,c);
    }

    console.log( foo({ a: 1 }) )

    console.log( foo({ a: 2, c: 5 }) )
```